# How can I recursively change permissions for files and directories on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, chmod

Every time I use `sudo chmod -R +755 *` or `sudo chmod -R +755 .`, it resets all of the file permissions to `000` in the directories and subdirectories.

If I run `sudo chmod +755 *`, it will properly add permissions for everything in the folder, but not subfolders.

Other variations, like

```
sudo find foldername -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ";"
```

also seem to reset permissions this way.

It also seems to ignore files and folders that begin with `.`, which is also undesired behavior.

Also, when I try to use `sudo chmod 0000 filename`, it only removes the write permissions. The read and execute permissions stay there. This also holds true when I use `os.chmod()` in Python3 (interpreter in the bash shell).

Windows 10 OS build is 17134.165

Comment: have you noticed that you're not using `-R` in your sudo command?

Comment: Edit your question to include the version of Windows your using, the version of WSL, be as specific as possible

Comment: @AhmedMasud in the first two commands I am using -R. In the third command it is still recursively working, although it removes permissions, rather than adds them.

Comment: So what WSL instance do you have installed?

Comment: Is there way to check version? When I searched for it, it looked like it was directly tied to the Windows version. That was explicit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/5q341a/how_to_know_which_version_of_wls_is_installed/. And it was implicit in the other answers I saw on stackexchange sites.

Comment: ... where are these files located? Are they Windows files?

Comment: If any Windows program modify any file then WSL shows that file permission to `000`.